# I can not connect to the server on Mysql workbench using Mac Os Sierra

Tags: mysql

I have installed MYSQL and MYSQL workbench but once I go into workbench to enter the root password I continuously get a message that says cannot connect to database server. I am totally lost and need help fixing this problem.

Comment: Have you started mysql server before trying to connect?

Comment: Yes it has been started already...

Comment: Can you connect from terminal: `mysql -hlocalhost -uUSER -pPASSWORD` or `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uUSER -pPASSWORD`?

Comment: Once I click on the MYSQL connection it prompts me to enter the server password which I do and then another message pops up that says cannot connect to database server  @mx0

Comment: Just tried connecting using terminal and each time it says "command not found' @mx0